# XML for path query to T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a pretty complex query that uses the 'XML for path' to return an XML. Now I need this query as a regular T-SQL query, but I have great difficulty converting this. I have searched for a tool or another topic that can convert this or give more information how to easily transform this query to a regular t-sql query. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT 
    UPPER([dataareaid]) AS Company, 
    accountnum AS Code,
    name + ' [' +    
                    CASE ENTERPRISENUMBER
                        WHEN 'BTW BE 0000.000.097' 
                        THEN  TMMONATIONALREGISTRATIONNUMBER
                        ELSE 
                            CASE countryregionid 
                                WHEN 'BE' 
                                THEN ENTERPRISENUMBER
                                ELSE countryregionid + VATNUM
                            END
                    END + ']' AS Name, 
    'false'    AS PaymentDenied, 
    PAYMTERMID         AS PaymentTermCode,
    currency   AS Currency,
    AX_TMM.dbo.IS_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE(dataareaid,accountnum) AS Active,
    --recid AS Id, 
    'email' as OrderFormat,
    'efinance@test.be' as OrderEmail,
    'nl-NL' as [Language],
    CASE ENTERPRISENUMBER
        WHEN 'BTW BE 0000.000.097' 
        THEN  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TMMONATIONALREGISTRATIONNUMBER, '.', ''), ',', ''),'-',''),' ', ''),'BTW', '')
        ELSE 
            CASE countryregionid 
                WHEN 'BE' 
                THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ENTERPRISENUMBER, '.', ''), ',', ''),'-',''),' ', ''),'BTW', '')
                ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((countryregionid + VATNUM), '.', ''), ',', ''),'-',''),' ', ''),'BTW', '')
            END
    END AS [SupplierIdentifiers/SupplierIdentifier/value],
    'PartyId' AS [SupplierIdentifiers/SupplierIdentifier/key],
    CASE ENTERPRISENUMBER
        WHEN 'BTW BE 0000.000.097' 
        THEN  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TMMONATIONALREGISTRATIONNUMBER, '.', ''), ',', ''),'-',''),' ', ''),'BTW', '')
        ELSE 
            CASE countryregionid 
                WHEN 'BE' 
                THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ENTERPRISENUMBER, '.', ''), ',', ''),'-',''),' ', ''),'BTW', '')
                ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((countryregionid + VATNUM), '.', ''), ',', ''),'-',''),' ', ''),'BTW', '')
            END
    END AS [AdditionalDatas/AdditionalData/value],
    'PartyId' AS [AdditionalDatas/AdditionalData/name],
    (SELECT 
        accountnum AS [Bban], 
        ACCOUNTID AS [Name], 
        name AS [AdditionalData1], 
        ENTERPRISENUMBER AS [AdditionalData2], 
        bankiban AS [Iban], 
        swiftno AS [Swift], 
        AX_TMM.dbo.IS_BANKACCOUNT_DEFAULT(dataareaid,vendaccount,accountid) AS IsDefault
        --vendtable.recid AS Supplierid
    FROM 
        vendbankaccount
    WHERE 
        vendaccount = vendtable.accountnum 
        and DATAAREAID = vendtable.DATAAREAID
        and (expirydate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' or expirydate > getdate())
    FOR xml path('SupplierBankAccount'), TYPE) AS [BankAccounts],     
    (SELECT (SELECT
                '' AS [ExternalCode],
                'PostalAddress' AS [Type], 
                'Maatschappelijke zetel ' + SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE.NAME AS [Name],
                'true' AS [IsDefault],
                maaccount + vendtable.DATAAREAID AS [ExternalIdentifier],



                (SELECT (SELECT 
                        'STREET_NAME' AS [AddressPartKey],
                        street AS [AddressPartText]
                        FROM 
                        SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION
                        ON ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION.ISOCODE = SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE.country
                        AND ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION.DATAAREAID = SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE.DATAAREAID
                        WHERE 
                        maaccount = vendtable.accountnum 
                        FOR xml path('SupplierAddressPart'), TYPE),
                    (SELECT 
        'POSTAL_ZONE' AS [AddressPartKey],
        zipcode AS [AddressPartText]
        FROM 
        SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE
        WHERE 
        maaccount = vendtable.accountnum 

    FOR xml path('SupplierAddressPart'), TYPE
        ),
        (SELECT 
        'CITY_NAME' AS [AddressPartKey],
        city AS [AddressPartText]
        FROM 
        SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE
        WHERE 
        maaccount = vendtable.accountnum 

    FOR xml path('SupplierAddressPart'), TYPE
        ),
        (SELECT 
        'COUNTRY' AS [AddressPartKey],
        ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION.NAME AS [AddressPartText]
        FROM 
        SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION
     ON ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION.ISOCODE = SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE.country
        AND ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION.DATAAREAID = SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE.DATAAREAID
    WHERE 
        maaccount = vendtable.accountnum 
    FOR xml path('SupplierAddressPart'), TYPE

        )
        FOR xml path('AddressParts'), TYPE)  
    FROM 
        SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION
     ON ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION.ISOCODE = SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE.country
        AND ADDRESSCOUNTRYREGION.DATAAREAID = SMARTMDCMASTERACCOUNTTABLE.DATAAREAID
    WHERE 
        maaccount = vendtable.accountnum 
  FOR xml path('SupplierAddress'), TYPE) FOR xml path('SupplierAddresses'), TYPE) 
 FROM  vendtable
 WHERE DATAAREAID = 'TMM'
 FOR xml path('Supplier'), ROOT ('DocumentElement')
```

Comment: The "nested'" nodes (every `,(SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM SomeWhere FOR XML PATH('xyz'),TYPE)` must be seen as `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`. Take them out delete the final `FOR XML...` line. Now you should get some data... Then add them as "normal" joins one after the other...

Comment: @Shnugo This indeed did the trick, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to read this, happy coding!